# How to show that the set $ U = \{ (x_1, x_2)^{T} \in \mathbb{R}^2: x_1+x_2=0 \} $ is may or may not a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

> How to show that the set $$ U = \{ (x_1, x_2)^{T} \in \mathbb{R}^2:
>  x_1+x_2=0 \} $$  is may or may not a subspace?

I have to show that $ 0 \in U $ and that is true since you can choose $x_1=0$ and $x_2=0$. Than you have to show that a vector $ x \in U $ multiplied with a scalar $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ stays in $U$:
$$\lambda \cdot x\in U$$
and that two vectors from $U$ stay in $U$:
$$ x,y\in U \Longrightarrow x+y\in U $$

But how do I show all these properties formally correct, I mean for example if you multiply a vector from $U$ with a scalar it is clear that the new vector also fulfills the property and has to be also in $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)\in U$, because $x_1+x_2=0+0=0$.

(2) If $(x_1,x_2), (y_1,y_2)\in U$ then $(x_1,x_2)+(y_1,y_2)\in U$, because $(x_1,x_2)+(y_1,y_2)=(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2)\in U$ and $(x_1+x_2)+(y_1+y_2)=(x_1+y_1)+(x_2+y_2)=0+0=0$.

(3) If $(x_1,x_2)\in U$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, then $\lambda (x_1,x_2)\in U$, because $\lambda (x_1,x_2)=(\lambda x_1,\lambda x_2)$ and $\lambda x_1+\lambda x_2=\lambda (x_1+x_2)=\lambda \cdot 0 = 0$.

We conclude that $U$ is a vector space.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Take $\lambda$ a scalar and $x = (x_1, x_2) \in U$, i.e., $x_1 + x_2 = 0$. Then $\lambda x = (\lambda x_1, \lambda x_2) \in U$ since

$$\lambda x_1 + \lambda x_2 = \lambda (x_1 + x_2) = \lambda \cdot 0 = 0.$$

Can you finish it now?

Comment: Yeah, would it be formally correct if I argue like that: (x1+y1)+(x2+y2) = x1+x2+y1+y2 = 0 + 0 = 0 for the two vectors in U?

Comment: @Operator Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

A more abstract, but shorter approach: $U$ is the kernel of the linear map

$$\begin{align*}&\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R,\\
&(x_1,x_2)^T\mapsto x_1+x_2.\end{align*}$$

And kernels of linear maps are always subspaces.